# Command line option to change Xcode DerivedData location

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I know the way to change the location of `DerivedData` using Xcode (Preferences->Locations->DerivedData..).

However the Mac that I am trying to build on is in a remote location with only ssh access. I want to build a specific project where I want to keep the DerivedData location relative to the project.

Whenever I build the project using `xcodebuild`, the files end up generating under `/Users/builduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` however I want them under '$PROJECT/target/DerivedData'

What is the command line equivalent to changing the DerivedData location setting as can be done via XCode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Xcode UI's DerivedData setting is passed to `xcodebuild` via the `-derivedDataPath` argument.  From `man xcodebuild`:

```
-derivedDataPath path
   Overrides the folder that should be used for derived data when performing a build action on a scheme in a workspace.
```

While it isn't clear what your goal is with changing the DerivedData path, you should be aware that there are some additional settings you can adjust in your app's build configuration to affect where the final build gets deployed. One of the phases of the build is the `install` phase which can move the final artifact(s) elsewhere. Settings that control these behaviors can be found under the 'Deployment' build settings group.  See `DSTROOT`, `INSTALL_PATH`, and `DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION` for additional options that may be helpful for reorganizing where your products get deployed.

Comment: But do you know where Xcode writes his default config for the DerivedData when configured from the UI, so we don't have to specify it from the xcodebuild command-line?

Comment: @dbernard Toss up a new SO question as this one was very specifically focused on modifying config via the CLI.  I'd be more than happy to give it an answer.

Comment: in my opinion the question asked by the poster "What is the command line equivalent to changing the DerivedData location setting as can be done via XCode?" is what I just asked. :)

Comment: @dbernard is clearly more context required than available in 550 characters; I'd be happy to help but not in the comments section of another question -- give the SO community the space to respond in a new question.

Comment: I definitely agree, but since this SO thread was one of the first search hit I got, may I suggest you Edit your answer to add a complement information for those looking to change the default config from command line? If you know the answer of course. ;)

Comment: @dbernard nah, my answer stands as-is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113155/discussion-between-dbernard-and-bryan-musial).

Comment: Downvoting for lack of context

Answer (score 2):

You probably should set this on a project basis, but if you need to change the Xcode default without going to the UI:

There's a plist file under ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

You can see and the change content via PlistBuddy:

> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c print ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
> and you can see the field:
> IDECustomDerivedDataLocation = DerivedData

If it's not set, you can just add it using PlistBuddy:

> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add IDECustomDerivedDataLocation string DerivedData" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist